# How to charge lithium ion battery?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have purchased and received [this battery](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-12V-Super-Strong-Capacity-4000MAH-Rechargeable-Li-ion-Battery-For-Camera-XP-/232233125141?var=&hash=item36122c4515:m:m-onwwIUgpJdQ-CH4JdcD7Q) from eBay. Upon opening it delivers 3v as oppose to 12v-10v and it has a petty output current. I am going to assume this is because it has not been charged much. I have a dc adapter similar to [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Universal-adapter-1000-mains-plug/dp/B008F86R1A) and i am wondering if i can plug the adapter into the female plug of the battery to let it charge. Would this work and if so what voltage should i set the adapter to for charging?

Comment: This is stated in the manual for the device. If you did not get a manual, tough luck, contact the seller because anyone else can only guess. Guessing means that it might break, possibly explode, so I hope no one tries.

Comment: ...Fortunately it says: _Short circuit, leakage protective, safety, no need to worry._

Comment: @pipe fortunately, I really like your sarcasm :)

Comment: @pipe
I did not receive any manual but since it says that, can i charge the battery with the method i suggested?

Comment: Assuming this battery had arrived fully charged - what was your plan to recharge it once you'd used it for a bit?

Comment: to do the method i suggested. It seems like the only logical method to me as there are just two dc plugs and I am just asking here for confirmation.

Comment: The device says that it needs a 12.6 volt input. No one knows what happens if you give it 12 volts. Best case, it will try to charge it but not completely succeed. Worst case, who knows.

Comment: so it will essentially work but wont be 100% efficient? 
also where did you get that information?

Comment: Unless you want to risk burning stuff down, get a Li-Ion charger. I've had a Li-Ion battery catch fire on my desk due to being improperly charged - its not much fun.

Comment: @pipe, If you feed a 3-cell lithium-polymer battery with under-voltage of 12V, it is well known what will happen. The only effect will be that the battery will be charged maybe to 30%-40% of its rated capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your battery delivers only 3V (while being obviously 3-cell battery), it means it is fully discharged and possibly damaged because of overdischarge. It may or may not recover if properly charged.

Before asking questions, you should familiarize yourself with methods of charging Li-Ion batteries. If you do so, you would discover that Li-ion cells must be **pre-charged** with small current (100-200mA) first until they get to about 3V level (each, meaning ~9V for your battery). Then the charge should go **at constant current** (0.5C is considered as safe level if battery specifications are nor known). Then, when the battery voltage reaches certain level as defined by details of the particular battery chemistry (4.2V can be a safe assumption, giving 3x4.2=12.6V for your battery), the charge should **proceed at constant voltage** (12.6V, or 4.2V per cell) until the current drops below 100-200mA. This would conclude the charge cycle.

Now it is up to you to decide if your "suggested method" fits  into above description. Keep in mind also that the cells in the battery pack are connected in series, so the voltage on inner cells might be distributed unevenly, causing imbalance, overvoltage, and undercharge. For optimal performance and longevity, batteries must have a more sophisticated, "balanced" charger, with more than two connected wires.

Comment: Great answer! Notice that 0.5C depends on accurate knowledge of C, the nominal battery capacity. It's sadly pretty common to see batteries be printed with capacities they don't have. By a factor >=5, sometimes. So yeah, go for 0.1C if you can't trust the battery

Comment: This answer assumes that the pack does not contain charging circuitry. Judging from the description _"Over current, over charge, over temperature, out of date protective."_, it does.

Comment: @pipe, do you read Chinese? Commendable... However, even if the cells include some silicon protection circuitry, it is not a charging circuit. The protection circuits usually are voltage-current monitors that shut off a pair of MOSFETs. I am not familiar with any simple battery pack that includes true charger, constant current to constant voltage. Again, after the charge is done, the charger must be bypassed by another low-impedance MOSFET. This is clearly cost-prohibitive.

Comment: @pipe I agree with Ali.  The battery may have protection circuitry, but it is very unlikely that it contains circuitry to properly charge the battery.  I would also like to echo the fact that the cells are most likely unusable if the battery is only 3V.  Generally 2.5V per cell, maybe down to 2V is as far as you want to go.  I believe at around 1.2V it starts plating lithium and once that happens the cell is useless.

Comment: ... and all of this is why I commented that I hope no one starts to _guess_ what the heck that device contains.

Comment: @pipe, I've seen several Li-Po packs, for quadcopters etc. Each cell does have a protection, dual-FET and a monitor, I believe this is mandatory these days, safety regulations. But the protection doesn't interfere with the standard charging algorithm - constant current, constant voltage. I think the OP "suggested method" can just work, assuming his DC adapter has a smooth current cut-off (constant current when overloaded) at 1-1.5A@12V, and he will have maybe 50% of battery rated capacity.

Comment: @pipe, see also this nice answer, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/86258/117785